# Yahoo Finance - incomplete retrieval components

Tags: python, api, yahoo-finance

I am trying to write down a function in python to retrieve the list of components of an Index.
So lets say I want to look at FTSE100 (^FTSE), I'd like to get all its components (100s of them) or even more information.

I can get more information about a components just by adding flags (see [this](http://resources.mdbitz.com/2010/02/understanding-yahoo-finance-stock-quotes-and-sl1d1t1c1ohgv/)).

However, given the index, I can only retrieve the first 51 components (first page of this: http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFTSE&c=0).

My function is:

```
at = '%40'
def getListComponents(symbol):
    url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%s%s&c=1&f=s' % (at, symbol)
    return urllib.urlopen(url).read().strip().strip('"')

Output example: 
'AAL.L"\r\n"ABF.L"\r\n"ADM.L"\r\n"ADN.L"\r\n"AGK.L"\r\n"AMEC.L"\r\n"ANTO.L"\r\n"ARM.L"\r\n"AV.L"\r\n"AZN.L"\r\n"BA.L"\r\n"BAB.L"\r\n"BARC.L"\r\n"BATS.L"\r\n"BG.L"\r\n"BLND.L"\r\n"BLT.L"\r\n"BNZL.L"\r\n"BP.L"\r\n"BRBY.L"\r\n"BSY.L"\r\n"BT-A.L"\r\n"CCL.L"\r\n"CNA.L"\r\n"CPG.L"\r\n"CPI.L"\r\n"CRDA.L"\r\n"CRH.L"\r\n"CSCG.L"\r\n"DGE.L"\r\n"ENRC.L"\r\n"EVR.L"\r\n"EXPN.L"\r\n"FRES.L"\r\n"GFS.L"\r\n"GKN.L"\r\n"GLEN.L"\r\n"GSK.L"\r\n"HL.L"\r\n"HMSO.L"\r\n"HSBA.L"\r\n"IAG.L"\r\n"IHG.L"\r\n"IMI.L"\r\n"IMT.L"\r\n"ITRK.L"\r\n"ITV.L"\r\n"JMAT.L"\r\n"KAZ.L"\r\n"KGF.L"\r\n"LAND.L'
```

This way getting parsing the components'titles is very easy.

How can I get the remaning 49 components? 
Take in consideration, that the components not retrieved could be even more in case I was looking at FTSE250 or higher.

**THE NO ANSWER:**

So I did some research, tried many combinations of flags, found and read this thread of comments:  code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvQuotesDownload ; AND I concluded that it's not possible to download all the components of an index as CSV.

If you have/had the same problem than just use BeautifulSoup. You may not like this approach, but there's not another way.

**[Solution to most of my problems](https://github.com/sic2/yahooFinanceApi)**

Answer (score 5):

If you're doing it that way, there's a little link at the top of the table that says `last` - which'll give you the last page number - `http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5EFTSE&c=2` (from your example) then split that out to create a range `range(number)` to loop over and request pages similar to how you're doing at the moment.

1. Open initial page
2. Extract link via lxml.html or BeautifulSoup
3. Parse out the last page number
4. Loop over number of pages retrieving each

On a side note, I'm pretty sure Yahoo! must have an API for some of this?

Comment: Yahoo has no official API (there's a thread somewhere in the web, where an Yahoo officer officially states that).
So, there's no way to get it as .csv file? I do not want to parse anything if possible.

Comment: @downvoter would you mind sharing how this answer could be improved?

Comment: yes, I'd like to have a link where I just change a flag/number indicating the page and retrieve all the components for that page. 

this way i can keep my code short and no parsing with BeautifulSoup or lxml.html.

Comment: @sic2 I believe that is exactly what he is suggesting - parse out the flag from the first page and iterate through that. The BS code would be very short (and clean), and the resulting range would provide your iteration variables (+1 to Jon, by the way :) ).

Comment: can you try to write down some code? I already tried to add the page flag to my link, but it did not work out.
Try this: http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EFTSE&c=2&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv And you'd still get the first page.

Comment: @JonClements : just wanted to say that you down vote when the answer does not satisfy you, not when the question is costructive.

Comment: @sic2 Really? - and to think I've been using SO incorrectly all this time ;)

Comment: @JonClements it should not be me saying that this is not the place to talk about this things, but it was you starting. lets stop it here and find the answer to the question, ok?

Comment: @JonClements i edited my question. hopefully it's more clear now :)

Comment: @pnuts : thanks, i've looked at all comments here: http://code.google.com/p/yahoo-finance-managed/wiki/csvQuotesDownload

and found that there's not a known way to get the list of all components :(

Answer (score 1):

I am new to Python and finding my feet.

I was looking for a solution to the same problem, but ended up writing my own.  My code is inefficient, lengthy and ugly - but it works and I will use if rarely.  I look forward to learning from someone wiser.

def getIndexComponents(symbol):

```
# function to retrieve the component list of equity index
# from Yahoo Finance, if available

import requests
p = 0

while p < 12:

    if p == 0:

        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5E' + symbol
        text = requests.get(url).content
                                                                              # </a></b></td><td
        componentSubset = [text[n-10:n] for n in xrange(len(text)) if text.find('</a></b></td><td', n) == n]

        for comp in range(len(componentSubset)):

            componentSubset[comp] = componentSubset[comp][(1+componentSubset[comp].index('>')):]

        components = componentSubset

    else:

        url = 'http://finance.yahoo.com/q/cp?s=%5E' + symbol + '&c=' + str(p)
        text = requests.get(url).content

        componentSubset = [text[n-10:n] for n in xrange(len(text)) if text.find('</a></b></td><td', n) == n]

        for comp in range(len(componentSubset)):

            componentSubset[comp] = componentSubset[comp][(1+componentSubset[comp].index('>')):]

        components.extend(componentSubset)

    p = p + 1

components = set(components)

return components
```

## seems to work

getIndexComponents('FTSE')