# Using the Yahoo Finance 'API' to get details of components of FTSE/DOW etc

Tags: api, yql, yahoo-finance

I am trying to get stock details (mainly the price) of the various companies contained within a larger grouping e.g. FTSE or DOW.

I can do this a crude way using the CSV download route within YQL...

```
select * from csv where url='http://download.finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=%40%5EFTSE&f=sl1d1t1c1ohgv&e=.csv'
```

This only returns 50 records although there are workarounds ([Yahoo Finance - incomplete retrieval components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13421364/yahoo-finance-incomplete-retrieval-components)).

I'd prefer to do this purely from the community tables, but I cannot workout the equivalent of @^FTSE using YQL. ^FTSE just returns the overall data from the FTSE. Is there an @ equivalent for the components?

Alternatively, is there a way to get a list of all of the components within a grouping such that I could then manually run a query containing all of their symbols? Such as

```
select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol in ("AAA","MM","AXP", ... all symbols in the DOW)
```